# RDP Dual Screen Linux

Tags: linux, rdp, monitors

we have a Windows Terminal Server and like to have Linux Clients which connect through rdp to the terminal server.

All works fine except that we cannot find a linux rdp client which supports multiple screens (like the windows rdp client does).

rdesktop -f and similarities also doesn't work because it results in one big virtual screen instead of two separate ones. So if you max an application inside remote desktop it will span over two monitors instead of just one.

Is there such a client available?

Answer (score 2):

There are only two RDP clients for Linux: rdesktop and FreeRDP.

`rdesktop` isn't actively developed, and as such it doesn't support many new features: encryption (network level authentication) and, as you noticed, dual screen.

[FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com) is actively developed with regular releases and support for network level authentication. I haven't tried using it to do a dual-head connection, but it is implemented in current development version (in git).

There are other RDP clients (like krdc) but they are just frontends to rdesktop or (possibly) FreeRDP.

Comment: +1 to xfreerdp, can't test it with multiple screens here, but if there is a client that can do it - this is it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you *require* free, but [Ericom Blaze](http://www.ericom.com/blaze_faqs.asp) works exceptionally well for multiple displays and can support Linux-based systems and thin clients.

Answer (score 0):

xfreerdp **does** support multiple screens (confirmed for at least 1.2.0-beta1), use the following option for that:

```
/multimon
```